# New Relic Memcached plugin installation location - App server or memcached server(s)?

Tags: plugins, memcached, newrelic

We have the New Relic PHP agent running on our 8 app servers. we have two memcached servers and would like to add the New Relic/ Meet Me Memcached plugin to grab memcached metrics. Should the memcached plugin be installed on the app servers or memcached servers? I read up on the installation instructions however this is not entirely clear.

Comment: You are probably asking on wrong server. Try e.g. http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

When I haven't used memcached  plugin yet, I do use MySQL, MongoDB and RabbitMQ plugings.
All of the can be installed or locally (on the same server where application located) or remotely.
I choosed the second  way - so I installed all these plugins on my management server and plugins collect metrics from all my mysql,mongo and rabbit servers. [other way you should install plugins and JRE  on many servers].